# Flashdevelop can't find events.ThrottleEvent in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I can't find it by manually searching the Flex directory either. I've downloaded the latest Flex 4.6 (updated Nov 2011 it seems) and ThrottleEvent is nowhere to be found. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what I need to be able to use ThrottleEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ThrottleEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ThrottleEvent.html) is in the flash.events.* package; meaning it is not part of the Flex Framework; but rather part of Flash--most likely in PlayerGlobals.swc.

You will not be able to access source code for this event; but you should be able to import it into your project and make use of the class, assuming your project is targeting Flash Player 11/AIR 3.2 or greater.

Comment: import flash.events.ThrottleEvent;
import flash.events.ThrottleType;
I've tried importing but FD can't find them. Where can I check to see if PlayerGlobals.swc is properly added?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Had to go into my project settings and change the target version to 11.2 or higher. Everything's working fine now. Thanks for your help!